# node js returns undefined from mongodb obejct inner value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, syntax, mongoose

I  have a store object i retrieved from mongodb,
I am interested in using the value store.comments.

i logged the store value and it is:

```
store:{ _id: 57e246f73e63d635cce3d174,
  __v: 0,
  comments: 57e246f73e63d635cce3d177,
  loc: [ 105.832321, 105.233272 ],
  name: '24 store',
  reportedFalse: [],
  products: [],
  currentRanking: 
   { likes: 57e246f73e63d635cce3d175,
     dislikes: 57e246f73e63d635cce3d176 },
  timePosted: Wed Sep 21 2016 11:38:15 GMT+0300 (Jerusalem Summer Time) },
```

then i logged the value of the object comments value -  **result.comments**:

```
store comments objectid: undefined
```

and it seems when i try to search later by the comments value that it doesn't succeed in searching with it. because the search returns null, although i see that in my db i have a corresponding object in "comments" table/schema with the same id....

```
Comments.findById(commentsId,function(commentsErr,commentsArrObj){
...
cb(null, commentsArrObj._id);
                    }
```

i get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null
```

heres part of my schema for reference:

```
        name: String,
        comments: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // each comment has a object id - responder, link curl? crud?  to his profile, profile pic, date time.
        timePosted : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        currentRanking: {
            likes: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // a votes document
            dislikes: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId // a votes document
        },
```

Comment: `comments` is **ObjectId**, so you cannot access `comments._id`

Comment: Hi, thanks. The second query is rather stupid i actuall search for an object and return its _id, it should still work...  the issue i think is on the first thing i mentioned, that i can't access result.comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your schema you have to use 'ref'

```
comments: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'comments'(modal name of comments)
```

to refer comments schema and use populate the comments to get comments data.

Comment: Thank you, ill try it. In what query can i access the actual object once i have the ref? lets say that the store.comments holds the ref... Thank you very much. ill read about it also.

Answer (score 0):

Console the error object "commentsErr" and then check what it is printing. If your commentsId type is changed to string then it may be the possible reason for not to finding the comments from schema. Try to convert it to ObjectId.

use:

```
Comments.findById(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id),function(commentsErr,commentsArrObj){
          cb(null, commentsArrObj._id);
})
```

Suggestion: Use mongoose to populate records using ref so that you need not to find separate query to get comments.