# TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null, only in production not dev

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My development server is crashed and won't restart. I get the following message when I check my logs. Below is the error

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
 TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null
    at /app/routes/index.js:220:53
    at model.Query.<anonymous>(/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4092:16)
    at /app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:273:21
    at /app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
Emitted 'error' event at:
     at model.Query.<anonymous(/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4094:13)
     at /app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:273:21
     at /app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

This message only occurs in production and not development, this is leading me to confusion. Here is the relevant code from file app/routes/index.js

```
// USER PROFILE
router.get("/users/:id", function(req, res) {
  User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundUser) {
    if(err) {
      req.flash("error", "Something went wrong.");
      res.redirect("/");
    }
Line 220 Comment.find().where('author').equals(foundUser._id).exec(function(err, comments) {
      if(err) {
        req.flash("error", "Something went wrong.");
        res.redirect("/");
      }
        res.render("show", {user: foundUser, comments: comments});
      })
    });
  });
```

I included my schema for comments below. I tried to use this solution [node js returns undefined from mongodb obejct inner value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612183/node-js-returns-undefined-from-mongodb-obejct-inner-value) but it did not work for the situation.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var CommentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    created: 
        {type: Date, default: Date.now}, 
     author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    blog: String
 });

 // pre-hook middleware to populate author in comment show route
CommentSchema.pre('findOne', function(next) {
 this.populate('author');
  next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", CommentSchema);
```

Edits: Based on the discussion in the comments I did a bit more testing  I was able to get the error to occur in development as well.
 I console.logged the output and this is what I got.

```
    This is the id { _id: 5af9af45f5a3b31bd4492e9d,
  username: 'mrboston',
  firstName: 'Mr',
  lastName: 'Boston',
  email: 'fake@yahoo.com',
  avatar: 'google.com',
  __v: 0,
  isAdmin: true }
This is the id undefined
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
```

I was logged in as my admin user at the time. I then tested the console.log(req.params)

```
{ id: '5af9af45f5a3b31bd4492e9d' }
{ id: 'google.com' }
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

Does this mean I am not being specific enough of my req.params query?

Edit 2:

Updated the code to this:

```
// USER PROFILE
router.get("/users/:id", function(req, res) {
  User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundUser) {
    if(err) {
      req.flash("error", "Something went wrong.");
      res.redirect("/");
    }
    if (!foundUser) {
    Comment.find().where('author').equals(foundUser._id).exec(function(err, comments) {
      if(err) {
        req.flash("error", "Something went wrong.");
        res.redirect("/");
      }
        res.render("show", {user: foundUser, comments: comments});
      });
    }
    });
  });
```

However run the app and click on the show user link, I get this error message

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'> 
    <title>Error 502 - Bad Gateway</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.c9.io/errors/style.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    .error_content {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.23);
        padding: 10px;
        width: 641px;
        margin: 25px 0;
        display: none;
    }

    #error-msg {
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="errorUnknown light">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <h1>Error 502 - Bad Gateway</h1>
      <div class="error_content" id="error-msg">
          <p>Please click <a href="javascript:location.reload(true)">here</a> to try again, if the issue persists please contact <a href="https://c9.io/support">support</a></p>
      </div>

      <a href="http://status.c9.io">Status Page</a> |
      <a href="https://c9.io/support">Support</a> |
      <a href="https://c9.io/dashboard.html">Dashboard</a> |
      <a href="https://c9.io">Home</a>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Edit 3: UserSchema

```
var     mongoose          = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");


var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    password: String,
    avatar: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date,
    isAdmin: {type: Boolean, default: false}
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports= mongoose.model("User",UserSchema);
```

Comment: As the error says `foundUser` is `null`. Probably meaning no user found with the id `req.params.id`.

Comment: Hi @jal_a, I did a bit more testing based on your comment, I was able to get the error to occur in development as well. I console.logged the output and this is what I got.                                       `This is the id { _id: 5af9af45f5a3b31bd4492e9d,
  username: 'mrboston',
  firstName: 'Mr',
  lastName: 'Boston',
  email: 'fake@yahoo.com',
  avatar: 'google.com',
  __v: 0,
  isAdmin: true }
This is the id undefined
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined`

Comment: I guess I am unsure why I have my admin users, which I am logged in as, as well as an undefined error as well

Comment: You should also log the `req.params` to see what you have in your request. Please edit your question and add the new info you included in the comment.

Comment: @jal_a Updated the comments, Would appreciate your insight on my findings after running req.params

Comment: You should `return` after `res.redirect()`. Don't continue the control flow of the callback after the error is detected.

Comment: Where does the request come from? Could it be a bug in your client code requesting user id "google.com"?

Comment: @jal_a I set up another user and got this error                                          `{ id: '5c479fdb95719b225d29f574' }
{ id: 'debugid.com' }` I believe what is happening is there an id for both User and avatar which would explain the google.com from the first one

Comment: So it must be the client code sending the wrong id. Anyways you should handle the not found user in your api `if (!foundUser) { /* ... */ }` and not query the comments if no user is found.

Comment: Hi @jal_a I updated the answer with my new code to try and correct this error, but I am getting a new error

Comment: Added user schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment but i believe error is occurring where 2 ID's are returning when u console log. 502 Error means that server didn't get valid response do u mind posting your schema for user because from there 2 id are returning somehow.

Edit: 2
I think i might have found your problem (not sure) but in pre-hook middleware

```
CommentSchema.pre('findOne', function(next) {
 this.populate('author');
      next();
});
```

Here you are using **findOne** but in route You are using **find** method thats why its not populating ur id and returns **null**. This is the Updated version.Please try this

```
router.get("/users/:id", function(req, res) {


 User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundUser) {
if(err) {
  req.flash("error", "Something went wrong.");
  res.redirect("/");
}
if (foundUser) {
Comment.findOne().where('author').equals(foundUser._id).exec(function(err, comments) {
  if(err) {
    req.flash("error", "Something went wrong.");
    res.redirect("/");
  }
    res.render("show", {user: foundUser, comments: comments});
  });
}
if(!foundUser){req.flash("error","User Not Found")}
```

Let me know If this fixes ur Error

Comment: Good hunch.  There *might* be problems if multiple users returned.  ALSO: `if (!foundUser) {
    Comment.find().where('author').equals(foundUser._id).exec(function(err, comments) ...`. ??WHAT??  If "foundUser" is undefined ... then we're going to de-reference "._id" of that undefined object???

Comment: Well actually that doesn't make any sense (!) sign should be removed because if u do that and u find a user using **User.FindById** u will never enter the **If** block. in simple English what this code does right now is that it finds user then if its found it doesn't do anything all because of (!) sign. Try removing that

Comment: Please mark the question answered Thanks :) Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Based on Shivam comment I updated the code to this:

```
if (foundUser) {
    Comment.find().where('author').equals(foundUser._id).exec(function(err, comments) {
      if(err) {
        req.flash("error", "Something went wrong.");
        res.redirect("/");
      }
        res.render("show", {user: foundUser, comments: comments});
      });
    }
    });
  });
```

And this worked. Thank you all for your help